# how to use ng-switch with ng-repeate in select

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to show and hide one of two select options based on an expression 
but it doesn't work well.  How can I make it work?  Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group has-error " ng-switch on="class">
        <label class="title_lable">{{class}}</label>
        <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="Tclass">
            <option ng-switch-when="7" ng-repeat="sd in ScientificDegree" value="{{sd.sub_cod}}">{{sd.Degree}}</option>
            <option ng-switch-when="8" ng-repeat="sp in Specialty" value="{{sp.Spec_Key}}">{{sp.Spec}}</option>
        </select> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i am taking the value of class from the url, if 7 show a certain ng-repeat, if 8 show the other ng-repeat, any idea

Answer (score 0):

Would be better if you include the controller's content in your question, but I tried to complete an example based on some assumptions. Your ng-switch looks good, so I think something is wrong in the controller. This is what I put in the controller to get it working:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.ScientificDegree = [{sub_cod:1,Degree:'Degree 1'}];
  $scope.Specialty = [{Spec_Key: 2, Spec: 'Specialty 2'}];
  $scope.TClass = '';
  $scope.class = 8;
});
```

Here's a plunker to see it working https://plnkr.co/edit/TjE2MvrHLfdI1umajtBx?p=preview

Comment: i am taking the value of class from the url, if 7 show a certain ng-repeat, if 8 show the other ng-repeat, any idea . when i use ng-show or hide , it brings the two ng-repeat inside the drop list